# Form Submit - Prevalidation throws IE off

Tags: php, mysql, html

Background: The website I am working on has a search bar at the top. The user inputs a part code for a product and the website returns information about that product.

So, I have a basic search bar that **posts** parameters from a HTML form into a PHP script, which then does a lookup on a MySQL server to get the Product.

The problem is because some part codes have "#" characters, I have to use Javascript to insert escape characters, otherwise I only get some of the part code in the PHP script.

*Example - 123#ABC would be read as 123.*

I use a hidden value in the form, which is populated with the Text Box value, modified by the escape() function in Javascript.

This is my code currently, it works in every browser except for IE.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

```
<script language="jscript">
    function changeTextBox()
    {
        hiddenSearch.value = escape(txtSearch.value);
        formSearch.submit;
    }
</script>

<form id="formSearch" name="Search" action="?page=search" method="post">
    Search by <u>Part Code</u> or <u>Description</u>
    <input id="txtSearch" type="text" size="35">
    <input id="hiddenSearch" name="Search" type="hidden">
    <input name="Submit" onclick='jscript:changeTextBox();' type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Escaping only in JavaScript will not stop a malicious user. Also what if the user presses enter instead of clicking the button? You'll at least need an onsubmit handler.

Comment: I would try something like `<form onsubmit="javascript:changeTextBox()" ...>` instead of onclick of the submit. Sometimes browsers have issues bubbling the events properly.

Comment: Andre We're in early days yet, the site isn't live yet. I'll keep that in mind though

Edit: Benno, thank you. That was the problem and it's now working :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your code will not do anything in any browser except IE, as long as you use the prefix `jscript:` in onclick. Furthermore this should be done on server-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at changes-- i think there were issues with your javascript.

```
   <script language="jscript">
        function changeTextBox()
        {
            document.getElementById("hiddenSearch").value = escape(document.getElementById("txtSearch").value);
            this.submit();
        }
    </script>

<form id="formSearch" name="Search" action="?page=search" method="post" onsubmit='changeText()'>
    Search by <u>Part Code</u> or <u>Description</u>
    <input id="txtSearch" type="text" size="35">
    <input id="hiddenSearch" name="Search" type="hidden">
    <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, the problem was that the onclick was in the wrong place. It should have been in the form tag.

Comment: thanks -- i modified the code slightly. I missed the jScript part-- onSubmit on form is the best bet.